# Using GNU Screen with 256 colors

Tags: gnu-screen

I recently installed GNU screen on a machine I ssh into. How do I get GNU screen to use 256 colors?

So  far, I've tried adding the following to my `.screenrc`:

```
term screen-256color
```

and

```
attrcolor b ".I"    # allow bold colors - necessary for some reason
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'   # tell screen how to set colors. AB = background, AF=foreground
defbce on    # use current bg color for erased chars
```

but neither worked.

In the login shell, before I start screen, when I run [this script](https://web.archive.org/web/20110225132303/http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/), which prints 256 colors, I get normal output. When I use the command `tput colors` I get the output `8`.

When I start screen and run the script, I get 16 colors mapped to 256 colors - there are large blocks of solid color. When I run `tput colors` I get `256` (when `term screen-256color` is in my .screenrc).

edit: I got it to work - I didn't configure screen with the `--enable-colors256` option.

Comment: What does `echo $COLORTERM` say?

Comment: `undefined`, but I got it to work - I recompiled it with the `--enable-colors256` option.

Comment: I have file names in color, but command prompt in black-and-white. Is you prompt in color also? (I mean - after you've re-build it yourself)

Answer (score 16):

I personally put it in ~/.bashrc

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

If that does not work, what terminal are you using ?

Comment: This is what fixed it for me. Need this in ~/.bashrc and the 3 lines listed in the original question for attrcolor, termcapinfo and defbce in the .screenrc. Thanks.

Comment: This worked. But adding the other stuff to ~/.screenrc makes everything output escape sequences instead of colors, like some sort of alien terminal.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Fixed an annoying bug I never got round to for ages.

Comment: `.bashrc` is a wrong place for setting `TERM` variable. See http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/TERM.html#MIS-CONFIGURATION

Answer (score 11):

If you built screen from source you'll need to recompile it with the 256 color flag enabled. Run `./configure --enable-colors256 && make && sudo make install`

Comment: This was my problem! I recompiled the source code, and added those three lines to my .screenrc!